# How do I solve java.lang.IllegalStateException in a GUI created using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I get the following error :

> Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on
>   FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5"

When this statement is executed :

```
 root.getChildren().add(carros);
```

The relevant code snippet is :

```
public void createCar(String origem, String destino){  
        Group carros = new Group();  
        carro1 = new Rectangle(30,15,Color.DARKMAGENTA);  
        carros.getChildren().add(carro1);  
        root.getChildren().add(carros);  
        animate(carros, (origem+"->"+destino) );   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying the change JavaFX elements in a thread different from the FX application thread. You can use

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
// place the code here, that you want to execute
});
```

to run code that modifies JavaFX elements. See here for other answers to this question [How to avoid Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083945/how-to-avoid-not-on-fx-application-thread-currentthread-javafx-application-th)

Comment: It helped me so much! Thank you!