# Timer (Clock) in JavaFX 1.8

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add a timer in my screen recording application being developed using JavaFX (IDE: NetBeans) and OS (Win 10). I am adding a timer now, which is to be used as:

User clicks on start recording, A Label on my application should start showing the time as 00:00:00, I have the time in seconds which is being printed on console even but when I use it to be displayed on application it just shows 0 Seconds. I am attaching code too. Kindly help. How can I refresh app interface or run timer when I have the value, It is just not updating.

Here you can see my app doesn't start timer; however, is being printed on console[App's Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkxae.png)   [Console Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbHLg.png)

```
    private void scheduleTimerTasks() {
        isRecording = true;
        int delay =50; 
        long period = 500;
                //1000 / 48;
        RecordTimer.reset();
        timerRecord = new Timer("Thread TimerRecord");
        timerCount = new Timer("Thread TimerCount");
        recorderTask = new ScreenRecorderTask(encoder, rectangle);
        countTask = new TimerCountTask(Timer);
        timerRecord.scheduleAtFixedRate(recorderTask, delay, period);
        timerCount.scheduleAtFixedRate(countTask, delay, period);
        Timer.setText(""+countTask.timeInSec+" s"); //Setting Label Text
        System.out.println(countTask.timeInSec);
        recordStateLabel.setText("recorder Started...");
    }
```

Comment: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

got this

Comment: Use Java 8 then? Instead of 7...

Comment: It is required, otherwise, I would have

Comment: Ok do it like this: `Platform.runLater(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override public void run() 
    {
        timer.setText(""+countTask.timeInSec+" s");
    }
});`

Comment: What is Platform? I need to import something or what? Its giving error on Platform only.

Comment: Aren't you using NetBeans? It should auto import `import javafx.application.Platform;`

Comment: Its still showing 0 s, however, I just checked my java version, and its 8. Idk why that error came. Apologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083945/how-to-avoid-not-on-fx-application-thread-currentthread-javafx-application-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AnimationTimer from javafx.animation.animationTimer, the handle' method of this timer will be called every frame.

Comment: It has started running but can you tell me why it is 2x of the actual time? Where can I set its FPS or whatever? If I record for 8 seconds, it is at 17 seconds

Comment: @AtifAziz The FPS shouldn't matter. The single argument of the `AniamtionTimer#handle(long)` method is the timestamp (in nanoseconds) of the frame. If you keep track of the previous timestamp and subtract it from the current timestamp you'll have the time elapsed (in nanoseconds) between the two frames.